# How to write a function that accepts two tuples, and returns the merged tuple in which all integers appears in ascending order?

Tags: python

> Write a function `merge(tup1, tup2)` that accepts two sorted tuples as parameters, and returns the merged tuple in which all integers appear in ascending order.
>
> You may assume that:
>
> - `tup1` and `tup2` each contain distinct integers sorted in ascending order.
> - Integers in `tup1`  are different from those in `tup2`.
> - Length of tuples may also vary.

I can't use Python's sorting function.

I've tried something like this, but failed public test cases such as:

- `merge((-1, 1, 3, 5), (-2, 4, 6, 7))` →   `(-2, -1, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)`
- `merge((-3, 8, 67, 100, 207), (-10, 20, 30, 40, 65, 80, 90))` → `(-10, -3, 8, 20, 30, 40, 65, 67, 80, 90, 100, 207)`
- `merge((-1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11), (-2, 0, 2, 4, 6))` → `(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11)`

```py
def merge(tup1, tup2):
    size_1 = len(tup1)
    size_2 = len(tup2)
  
    res = ()
    i, j = 0, 0
  
    while i < size_1 and j < size_2:
        if tup1(i) < tup2(j):
            res.append(tup1(i))
            i += 1
  
        else:
            res.append(tup2(j))
            j += 1
    
    return res = res + tup1(i:) + tup2(j:)
```

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and replace ambiguous "*it doesn't seem to work*" with your actual findings.

Comment: Can't use python's sorting function

Comment: Oh sorry I was trying to convert to list, then back to a tuple. But I guess tuple can't do that? What would be recommended here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (algorithm) is fine, you just have a few syntax errors:

- Indexing is done with `[..]`, not `(...)`.
- You can either `return` or assign - not both.

And a logical (attribute) error:

- Tuples don't have `append` - you can concatenate them by using addition (or just by using lists and converting in the end to a tuple).

Your code with the syntax errors fixed and using lists seems to work fine:

```py
def merge(tup1, tup2):
    size_1 = len(tup1)
    size_2 = len(tup2)

    res = []
    i, j = 0, 0

    while i < size_1 and j < size_2:
        if tup1[i] < tup2[j]:
            res.append(tup1[i])
            i += 1

        else:
            res.append(tup2[j])
            j += 1

    res.extend(tup1[i:])
    res.extend(tup2[j:])
    return res
```

Answer (score -2):

Unpack both tuples into a list using *operator, sort and convert to tuple.

```
merge = lambda t1, t2: tuple(sorted([*t1, *t2]))
```

Comment: OP "*Can't use python's sorting function*"

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes since this "no sort" requirement was nowhere stated in the question (Comments don't count)

Comment: Merging can be done in a single pass. There's no need for an O(n log n) sort.

Answer (score -2):

Since tuples are immutable in Python, I would loop over them to copy the items one by one into a list, sort that list with `.sort()`, and then convert it into a tuple.

Comment: Both tuples are already sorted, so you just need a bit of intelligence in the "*copy the items one by one*" process. No need to re-sort the result.